# Exchange EWS Managed API - unexpected token in XML

Tags: c#, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

Im trying to write a simple sample program which checks for any new mail on an Exchange 2010 server. As far as I can tell, the code I've got should work fine.

I setup the service as follows:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@domain.co.uk", "password");

service.Url = new Uri("https://address/owa");
```

Upon executing the following code:

```
        int unreadMail = 0;

        // Add a search filter that searches on the body or subject.
        List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "Defense"));

        // Create the search filter.
        SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, searchFilterCollection.ToArray());

        // Create a view with a page size of 50.
        ItemView view = new ItemView(50);

        // Identify the Subject and DateTimeReceived properties to return.
        // Indicate that the base property will be the item identifier
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived);

        // Order the search results by the DateTimeReceived in descending order.
        view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);

        // Set the traversal to shallow. (Shallow is the default option; other options are Associated and SoftDeleted.)
        view.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;

        // Send the request to search the Inbox and get the results.
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);

        // Process each item.
        foreach (Item myItem in findResults.Items)
        {
            if (myItem is EmailMessage)
            {
                if (myItem.IsNew) unreadMail++;

            }
        }
```

I get this error (on the FindItemResults line):

```
'>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 63.
```

This appears to be an error in the XML the API is actually generating, I've tried a few different lots of code (all along the same lines) and not found anything that works.

Any ideas? At a bit of a loss when it comes directly from the API!

Cheers, Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, fixed it - needed to point my service to:

https://servername/ews/Exchange.asmx

and provide regular domain login details such as "username", "password" in order to connect!